# how to change the width of the UIPickerView in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipickerview

how to change the width of the UIPickerView in objective C, I am using the following code,

```
    tempFiled = Data;
    [tempFiled resignFirstResponder];
    CGSize sizeOfPopover = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
    CGPoint positionOfPopover = CGPointMake(32, 325);
    [popOverControllerWithPicker presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(positionOfPopover.x, positionOfPopover.y+10, 500, sizeOfPopover.height)
         inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

But when i am trying to change the width in CGSize sizeOfPopover = CGSizeMake(200, 200); its not changing, i want to reduce the size of the picker.

Comment: let me guess... the popover is changing size but not the `UIPickerView` inside it?

Comment: The width of the `UIPickerView` is kind of undocumented magic. There are only a couple of values that work properly, basically the width of the iPhone in either portrait or landscape (so either 320 points or 640 points). It doesn't like to be anything else. Unfortunately, this behavior is not documented.

Comment: can you alter the frame property of the `UIPickerView` inside your popover?  That might allow you to change the height and width....

Comment: @MichaelDautermann no not even the popover is not getting changed. Sorry for typing it wrong first.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I tried changing the frame property also, but there was no change in the width and height.I am able to increase but not able to decrease the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and solved it this way:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGRect frame = bpsPicker.frame;
    frame.size.width = 100; // width to be displayed on popover controller
    bpsPicker.frame = frame;

}
```

Using ViewDidLoad() is too early to alter this value.

To be clear the viewWillAppear is in the UIViewController that is passed to the UIPopover (here called 'MyViewController.m').So,

```
self.myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil] ;
self.myViewController.delegate = self;
self.myViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 360); // or whatever

self.myViewControllerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.myViewController] ; 

[self.myViewControllerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.myToolBarButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny  animated:YES];
```